# Is there an equivalent to using the double colon operator (::) with source() in R?

Tags: r, function, scope, namespaces

Since my project contains a lot of different files that just contain function definitions (which I then `source()` in a main workflow file), I can often forget exactly which function is contained in which file.

This wouldn't be a problem if I could use my sourced files like packages with a syntax like this: `source("file.r")::function()`. Of course, that code returns an error (`Error: unexpected '::' in "source("file.r")::"`), but I'm hoping there is an equivalent operator I can use for sourced files.

Comment: Have a look at the [box](https://github.com/klmr/box) package and its *modules* - quite neat workflow for larger projects.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but I highly recommend a personal R package. If you need setting up a personal R package you could try {personalr}.
https://mrcaseb.github.io/personalr/
(Note: I am the maintainer of that package)

Comment: One downside is that if you rearrange your functions into different files then your function calls will have to be modified.  Anyways some possibilities are (1) The import package is another package that handles this.   (2) simply make a table for yourself `grep function *.R` or `findstr function *.R` on Windows or (3) put a comment in each function indicating which file it is in.  Then just list the function's source to find out.  If you move the functions the source will need to be modified but the calls won't need to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use environments to effect this, using `$` in lieu of `::`.

If you have files:

- `file1.R`

  ```r
  func1 <- function(x) x + 1
  func2 <- function(y) y + 2
  ```
- `file2.R`

  ```r
  func3 <- function(x) x + 3
  func4 <- function(y) y + 4
  ```

then you can create environments for them and load them into there with `local=`:

```r
e1 <- new.env()
source("file1.R", local = e1)
e2 <- new.env()
source("file2.R", local = e2)
ls()
# [1] "e1" "e2"
e1$func1(1)
# [1] 2
e1$func2(1)
# [1] 3
e2$func3(1)
# [1] 4
e2$func4(1)
# [1] 5
```

Note: functions defined in `file2.R` will not "see" functions in `file1.R`. This has some pros and cons:

- **Pro**: namespace pollution is reduced. If you have constants defined in a file that the functions within it must be able to reference, then this works well. Those constants are in a sense "private" (very loosely speaking) to functions in that same file.
- **Con**: unlike a "package", functions that must see each other must either be defined in the same file or must have another mechanism for determining where to find the other functions.